# How can I populate data from a model in Flask Select Dropdown?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am very new in Flask. I am trying to populate patients list in Treatment Form dropdown select. But it is not showing the patients list. I think TreatmentForm need to be tweak. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Forms.py

```
class PatientForm(FlaskForm):
  name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
  age = StringField('Age', validators=[DataRequired()])
  gender = SelectField('Gender', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('Male'),('Female')])
  identity_number = StringField('IC / Passport / Matric Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
  contact_number = StringField('Contact Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
  submit = SubmitField('Submit')

class TreatmentForm(FlaskForm):
  patient = SelectField('Patient', choices=[Patient.query.all()], validators=[DataRequired()])
  medication = SelectField('Medication', choices=[("1", "One")], validators=[DataRequired()])
  test = StringField('Test', validators=[DataRequired()])
  cost = FloatField('Cost', validators=[DataRequired()])
  initials = TextAreaField('Initials', validators=[DataRequired()])
  submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Models.py

```
class Patient(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  ame = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
  age = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
  gender = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
  identity_number = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
  patient_created_at = db.Column(db.Date, default = date.today())
  contact_number = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
  doctor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('doctor.id'), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"Medication('{self.id}', '{self.name}')"



class Treatement(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  patient = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
  treatment_created_at = db.Column(db.Date, default=date.today())
  medication = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
  test = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
  cost = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
  initials = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
  doctor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('doctor.id'), nullable=False)
```

Routes.py

```
@app.route("/patient/new", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_patient():
  form = PatientForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    patient = Patient(name=form.name.data, age=form.age.data, gender=form.gender.data, 
    identity_number=form.identity_number.data,contact_number=form.contact_number.data, 
    doctor=current_user)
    db.session.add(patient)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Patient has been registered!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('patients'))
 return render_template('create_patient.html', title='Register New patient', form=form, legend='Register New patient')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your patient model, you have a typo. I assumed "ame" was supposed to be "name"?
Once you fix that, Try this. I assumed you wanted patient select field  in the treatment form to display name, but I wasn't sure. Here is a solution for that.

```
    def init_TreatmentForm():
    patient_names =  []
    patientObjects = Patient.query.all()
    for patientObject in patientObjects:
        patient_names.append(patientObject.name)


        class TreatmentForm(FlaskForm):
            patient = SelectField('Patient', choices=patient_names, validators=[DataRequired()])
            medication = SelectField('Medication', choices=[("1", "One")], validators=[DataRequired()])
            test = StringField('Test', validators=[DataRequired()])
            cost = FloatField('Cost', validators=[DataRequired()])
            initials = TextAreaField('Initials', validators=[DataRequired()])
            submit = SubmitField('Submit')

        return TreatmentForm
```

In your route when you set up your treatment form, you will now need to do this.

```
from models import init_TreatmentForm

treatmentFormObject = init_TreatmentForm()
treatment_form = treatmentFormObject()
```

Include this form in the render template parameters like you did w/ form in your patients route

Comment: Did this answer help you?